# How to make sure that in a string last 2 characters have at least one digit with python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to parse some specific text for like below. I have tried to use python re with
`r'[A-Z]{5}[A-Z0-9]{2}'` expression but this is giving me unwanted text also. Please see below for the expected output.

Conditions:

1. The string should be a total of 7 Characters.
2. The string last 2 characters should be only 2 Digits or have at least 1 Digit with [A-Z] letters

Given String:
`"DHKGNC1, DHDHK32, DHKGN1K, SOME, GARBAGE, TEXT"`

Expected output: `['DHKGNC1', 'DHDHK32', 'DHKGN1K']`

Actual output: `['DHKGNC1', 'DHDHK32', 'DHKGN1K', 'GARBAGE']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `[A-Z0-9]{2}`, use `([A-Z0-9][0-9])|([0-9][A-Z0-9])`

That is, one or the other has to be a digit.

```
re.findall(r'([A-Z]{5}(?:(?:[A-Z0-9][0-9])|(?:[0-9][A-Z0-9])))', "DHKGNC1, DHDHK32, DHKGN1K, SOME, GARBAGE, TEXT")
['DHKGNC1', 'DHDHK32', 'DHKGN1K']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following regex may work:

```
[A-Z]{5}([A-Z]?[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]?)
```

Comment: `[A-z]` isn't really well-defined; did you mean `[A-Z]`?

Comment: Yes, sorry meant A-Z. Have edited the original answer